# Declarative pipeline script for "workspace" option selector of copy artifacts plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I want to copy few files and folders of last completed build's workspace to current build and then do something with it. I found to do it using free style job with **Copy from WORKSPACE of latest completed build** option. But I would like to do the same from declarative pipeline script. I got following snipped from snippet generator of Jenkins.

```
copyArtifacts filter: 'file.xml', projectName: 'NewTestPipeline', selector: workspace(), target: 'out/'
```

But its not working with pipeline script, says no such file.
Note: I am not archiving the artifacts and dont want to archive. I jus need to copy files from last builds workspace.

Comment: If you use dynamic agents (like (tmp) Docker and Kubernetes Agents), run the job on multiple agents or clear the workspace before and after a Job Run (Settings); Access to the original (previous) workspace is/might not possible or guaranteed. In this case you need to archive or use storage/repository external to Jenkins to save and retrieve the artifact(s)